# How to position the screen using HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: html

How do you position your screen when you click a text containing a link.

For example: If I click on `<a href"myWebsite.com">Contact</a>`
When I click that I want my screen to automatically scroll down to the contacts, in the bottom of my website.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href

Comment: Just add an id to the element, then use the id as a hash on the url. [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224577/how-to-position-the-screen-using-html-css-js#wmd-input)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use the anchor element `<a>` where href points to an element in your page.

Example:

```html
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>

<a href="#other-fruits">Go to other fruits</a>

<h2 id="apples">Apples</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi justo, viverra vel sodales a, vehicula et dolor. Etiam hendrerit, magna non condimentum faucibus, lorem elit tempus leo, sit amet porta quam felis vitae nisl. Pellentesque ut arcu neque. Ut gravida egestas lectus, eu maximus velit. Aenean sed pulvinar ipsum. In finibus metus id urna elementum aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi id semper massa. Proin eu gravida neque, eu tincidunt justo. Vestibulum ac molestie augue. Quisque vestibulum egestas pulvinar. Donec congue ligula vitae libero vestibulum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<h2 id="bananas">Bananas</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi justo, viverra vel sodales a, vehicula et dolor. Etiam hendrerit, magna non condimentum faucibus, lorem elit tempus leo, sit amet porta quam felis vitae nisl. Pellentesque ut arcu neque. Ut gravida egestas lectus, eu maximus velit. Aenean sed pulvinar ipsum. In finibus metus id urna elementum aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi id semper massa. Proin eu gravida neque, eu tincidunt justo. Vestibulum ac molestie augue. Quisque vestibulum egestas pulvinar. Donec congue ligula vitae libero vestibulum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<h2 id="other-fruits">Other fruits</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi justo, viverra vel sodales a, vehicula et dolor. Etiam hendrerit, magna non condimentum faucibus, lorem elit tempus leo, sit amet porta quam felis vitae nisl. Pellentesque ut arcu neque. Ut gravida egestas lectus, eu maximus velit. Aenean sed pulvinar ipsum. In finibus metus id urna elementum aliquam. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi id semper massa. Proin eu gravida neque, eu tincidunt justo. Vestibulum ac molestie augue. Quisque vestibulum egestas pulvinar. Donec congue ligula vitae libero vestibulum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```